# JavaScript. Trocar uma string para um operador

Tags: javascript

Olá, gostaria de saber se tem como eu pegar o valor `+` no meio se uma `string` e deixar ele como um *operador* ?

Exemplo:

De:

```
var string = "15 + 20 + 30"
```

Para:

```
var convert = "15" + "20" + "30"
```

Obs: a quantidade dos valores dentro é indefinida podendo ser `"15 + 15"` ou até mesmo `"1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1"`

Comment: Da pra fazer algo bem simples tipo `'1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1'.split('+').reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) que computa uma string trantando como expressão:

```js
console.log(eval("1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1"));

// pode inclusive usar expressões mais complexas:
var x = "10";
console.log(eval("x/(2+3)"));
```

Comment: quem negativou pode explicar o que essa resposta tem de ruim se ela responde exatamente o que foi perguntado, com exemplo e também link para a documentação original???

Comment: Só quem votou negativo pode responder isso com precisão, mas muito provavelmente é porque sua resposta não explica muito sobre o eval, e o link que você compartilhou tem um tópico `Never use eval()!`. Teoricamente sua referência diz pra nunca usar sua resposta

Comment: pode até ser, mas é igual dizer "olha tem um comando format aqui, mas nunca use" :) eu li isso e achei a forma como está escrito exagerada, se fosse para nunca usar deveria ser removida :) mas agraço o comentário Rafael. Um simples if pode ser tão desastroso quanto se mal usado

Comment: Obrigado pela dica =D utilizei o eval() na minha calculadora. ajudou muito

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode fazer um split pelo operador, o resutlado será um array de string com os valores:

```js
var string = '15 + 15 + 15';
var convert = string.split('+');

// convert > ["15", "15", "15"]

// para somar: 
var sum = 0;
convert.forEach( num => {
  sum += parseInt(num);
})
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica :D